# Busca Firebase por vários campos

Tags: android, firebase

Eu consigo fazer a busca pelo searchview pegando os dados do Firebase somente pelo item nomeOrganizacao como faço para pesquisar por qualquer campo ao mesmo tempo.
Ex: Eu posso pesquisar São Paulo, Máquinas, SENAI, etc e sempre apareça o mesmo item do recyclerview.

```
 Query Q = organizacao.orderByChild("nomeOrganizacao").
 startAt(newText).endAt(newText + "\uf8ff");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente o Firebase não tem ainda uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Então só vou conseguir fazer a busca com o Firebase somente por 1 só campo e também somente pela primeira letra da palavra?

Comment: Sim. A única forma de fazer buscas complexas no Firebase é utilizando outros serviços como [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) ou [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/)... Eles até criaram [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) para facilitar isso.